# Pandas: Group rows by similar column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Having a pandas df that looks like this:

```
      x  column     word  size  y   
0  1552       0    word1   218  2           
1  1775       1    word2    53  2        
2  1999       2    word3   163  2               
3  2200       3    word4   142  2                
4  2345       4    word5   129  2
```

I would like to group the rows based on the condition:
`abs(current_row_x + current_row_size - next_row_x) < 10`

So, the desired df here would be:

```
      x  column     word         size  y   
0  1552       0     word1 word2   271  2                   
1  1999       2     word3         163  2               
3  2200       3     word4 word5   271  2
```

What I've tried by now is the following:

```
df = df.groupby((abs(df.x + df.size - df.x.shift(1)) < 10).cumsum()).agg({'y':'min', 'x':'min', 'size':'sum', 'column':'min', 'word':' '.join})
```

But the result df is not quite what I'm expecting and also the groupby condition seems to be ignored.

Any possible approach to this? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this condition is setup appropriately? My output is not matching.

Comment: Group based on `abs(current_row_x + current_row_size - next_row_x) < 10` is what i'm looking to accomplish. **x** is where the word starts, **size** is the word size. So if **x** + **size** is close enough to the next word (**x** from the next df row), I want to group them. Maybe the `df = df.groupby((abs(df.x + df.size - df.x.shift(1)) < 10).cumsum()).agg({'y':'min', 'x':'min', 'size':'sum', 'column':'min', 'word':' '.join}) ` approach is totally wrong. I've tried different approaches but no luck. The goal is to get the desired df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling some hours I made it work.

Strating from this df:

```
      x  column     word  size  y   
0  1552       0    word1   218  2           
1  1775       1    word2    53  2        
2  1999       2    word3   163  2               
3  2200       3    word4   142  2                
4  2345       4    word5   129  2
```

The first thing I've done is to add another column **x1** representing the sum of **x** and **size**:

```
df["x1"] = df["x"] + df["size"]
```

So now, my df looks like this:

```
      x  column   word  size  y    x1
0  1552       0  word1   218  2  1770
1  1775       1  word2    53  2  1828
2  1999       2  word3   163  2  2162
3  2200       3  word4   142  2  2342
4  2345       4  word5   129  2  2474
```

Now, I perfom the grouping with this condition `(df.x - df.x1.shift(1)) > 10)`:

```
df = df.groupby(((df.x - df.x1.shift(1)) > 10).cumsum()).agg({'y':'min', 'x':'min', 'size':'sum', 'column':'min', 'word':' '.join})
```

And the result is the expected:

```
   y     x  size  column         word
0  2  1552   271       0  word1 word2
1  2  1999   163       2        word3
2  2  2200   271       3  word4 word5
```

Got it working, but I really don't know why the gouping condition `(abs(df.x + df.size - df.x.shift(1)) < 10)` was failing. Maybe someone with more experience can explain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the same output, but try:

```
s = abs(df['x'] + df['size'] - df['x'].shift(-1)) < 10
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'x' : 'first', 'column' : 'first',
                        'word' : lambda x: ' '.join(list(x)), 'size' : 'sum', 'y' : 'first'})
df

Out[1]: 
          x  column               word  size  y
False  1775       1  word2 word3 word5   345  2
True   1552       0        word1 word4   360  2
```

Alternatively, with `.groupby` and `.cumcount`:

```
s = df.groupby((abs(df['x'] + df['size'] - df['x'].shift(-1)) < 10)).cumcount()
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'x' : 'first', 'column' : 'first',
                        'word' : lambda x: ' '.join(list(x)), 'size' : 'sum', 'y' : 'first'})
df
Out[2]: 
      x  column         word  size  y
0  1552       0  word1 word2   271  2
1  1999       2  word3 word4   305  2
2  2345       4        word5   129  2
```

finally with `.cumsum()` (I seem to be getting everything except the output you have posted :) !):

```
s = ((abs(df['x'] + df['size'] - df['x'].shift(-1)) < 10)).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'x' : 'first', 'column' : 'first',
                        'word' : lambda x: ' '.join(list(x)), 'size' : 'sum', 'y' : 'first'})
df
Out[2]: 
      x  column               word  size  y
1  1552       0  word1 word2 word3   434  2
2  2200       3        word4 word5   271  2
```